# apply css to another span on slide of a carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel running at my site

```
div id="weekCarousel_{{$index}}" class="carousel slide">
    <a href="#weekCarousel_{{$index}}" data-slide="prev" class="prevweek">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </a>
    <a href="#weekCarousel_{{$index}}" data-slide="next" class="nextweek">
        <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I would like to add a css class for span whenever this carousel gets slided

```
<span id="displayer">.........</span>
```

this is my span tag any suggestions?

Comment: I think this is a copy/paste error, but you missed a `<` before `div id="weekCarousel_{{$index}}" class="carousel slide">`

Comment: You have an `event` with name `slide.bs.carousel` which triggers whenever a `slide` occurs!! You can make use of it to add or remove `class`! since there isn't much code I cay suggest only this much!

Comment: Guruprasad Rao - thankyou also found an another method for 'slid' to trigger slid event after carousel slid is done  . fiddle is here:http://jsfiddle.net/9fwuq/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On slide event:

```
$('.your-class').removeClass('your-class');
$('div#displayer').addClass('your-class');
```

Comment: syntax for onslide plzz